# UIImage + SDWebImage not showing some JPG files. Sometimes show JPEG. PNG working

Tags: ios, uiimageview, sdwebimage

This has been bugging me and my team for over 2 days.

We're using SDWebImage to download and display pics.
PNG files always work.
JPG files almost always do not show. When I convert the file to png (same name, different suffix), it is shown.
I've discovered that sometimes changing the file suffix from jpg to jpeg works.

The code:

```
 [dataContent.imageBg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

Comment: can you share the image url ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well - We've found the problem.

Apparently the mime type for .jpg reported by our server was `application.jpg`. .jpeg's mime type was reported correctly as `image/jpeg`.

As SDWebImage validates mime type (why b.t.w?), it rejected our .jpg files.

We've corrected the mime type reported by server to be `image/jpeg` and everything is working fine now.